Laravel Test Cookie is Encrypted Despite Being Excluded from EncryptCookies Middleware
I’m working on a Laravel 11 project and have a cookie that is excluded from being encrypted in the EncryptCookies middleware. Here’s how I set it in my middleware:
class EncryptCookies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The names of the cookies that should not be encrypted.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $except = [
        'pattr',
    ];
}

In my unit test, I set the cookie like this:
public function test_repeat_guest_can_store_an_attribution(): void
{
    $pattr = uniqid();

    $response = $this->withCookie('pattr', $pattr)
        ->withoutExceptionHandling()
        ->post('api/attributions', [
            'utm_source' => 'Facebook',
        ]);
}

However, when I dd the value of the cookie in my controller, it’s still showing up as encrypted:
$cookie_id = uniqid();
if ($request->hasCookie('pattr')) {
    $cookie_id = $request->cookie('pattr');
    dd($cookie_id);
}

The output I get looks like this (encrypted cookie):
"EXAMPLE6Im1sRFdhSHdMdGhCZkFUU01pY0FMSUE9PSIsInZEXAMPLEjoiQlhkWENUWW1lZ25Vckt1QnhEWWZXTjN6TzRIS011EXAMPLEMTk9RR3ZjaTRDdVNFTEXAMPLEad0toVEcrdzhDQkpHd3Q2cmE0Rk9jZ0tMQWcvdXg0d1E9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjY5ZTFmMmEyNTYwNDczNEXAMPLEkYTA3OGFlODI0ZTkxZDU5YmRiNjQ2ZjVjMTRjMWJkMGZkN2MxYjQzOTEzOTMiLCJ0YWcEXAMPLE=="

I expected the cookie to remain unencrypted since I added it to the $except array in the EncryptCookies middleware. I also tried disabling the middleware in my test with withoutMiddleware() but the issue persists.
Why is the cookie still being encrypted in my unit test, and how can I fix it so that the cookie remains unencrypted?

Does the same thing happen when you use this syntax?
$cookies = ['name' => 'value'];
$response = $this->call('POST', '/route', [], $cookies);

@JonMenard amazing, this fixed it if you want to post an answer I can accept it.

Try to use this syntax instead, I can't explain why but there is some funny behaviour with cookies in Laravel testing
$cookies = ['name' => 'value']; 
$response = $this->call('POST', '/route', [], $cookies);


I can't set it directly on the "EncryptCookies" because this file is from the Laravel Framework core, so the custom code is lost when the composer update is run.
I had success setting the cookie so it is not encrypted on the "AppServiceProvider" using the "EncryptCookies" there.
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        EncryptCookies::except(['cookie_name_1','cookie_name_2','cookie_name_N']);
    }
}


I think this will work on the site, but in the unit tests (as per the question) its still encrypted.

In laravel 11 you can exclude cookies from encryption as follow
in

bootstrap/app.php

->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->encryptCookies(except: [
        'cookie_name_to_exclude',
    ]);
})

you can find in official docs at here

Thanks. Thats what I'm doing in my first code snippet, the cookies aren't encrypted on the actual site, but middleware isn't run in unit tests so they are still encrypted there.
